# Patchwork is squashing my ggplot that has correct aspect when click zoom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, aspect

I've tried to make this question clear and I'm sorry that I have not been able to provide an MRE as I wouldn't even know where to begin to make this a MRE, but let me know if you can identify an obvious issue?

In my R script when I run the graph and then click zoom, the following appears: [Zoom correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIiFy.png)

In markdown and also in the bottom right of plots (before clicking zoom), I get the following squashed and misformatted image [image: Markdown misformatted image]

Let me know if you can help in any way and I'm sorry if this is not a well worded question.

I guess I want to know in short how to edit my markdown images to appear like they do when I click Zoom function. Sorry I'm pretty new to R and SO.

Comment: when you zoom your plot in Rstudio, the dimensions of the resulting plot are very different from the dimensions in your markdown document. Try changing `fig.width` and `fig.height` in the chunk options. These are in inches.

Comment: @AdroMine you are the best!!!!!! It worked, cheers my bro